# Hiding Y2 axis labels in dygraphs does not reclaim space on the right side of the canvas

Tags: dygraphs

How do I hide the Y2 axis on the canvas and reclaim the space when drawYAxis: false is set globally. The left and right side have labels hidden but ~ 50px of padding remain unclaimed in the right side of the graph.  The left side (Y1) is completely reclaimed as expected.

```
drawYAxis: false,
series: {
                'Altitude': {
                    axis: 'Y2',
                    drawYAxis: false <-- this doesn't work.
                }
        },
        axes: {
            x: {
                axisLabelFormatter: xAxisLabelFormatter,
                axisLabelFontSize: 12,
                axisLabelColor: "#FFF"
            },
            y2: {
                drawYAxis: false <-- neither does this.
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bug. I've fixed it here:
https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/commit/9f890c23ad80924d0a30f3a14f8680b7c2d6318e

If you grab a fresh copy of dygraphs from github or dygraphs.com, you'll get the fix.